# pg_dump from Azure Postgres Service which contains large data set

Tags: postgresql, azure, hl7-fhir, pg-dump, hapi-fhir

We are facing well-known pg_dumps effeciency problems in terms of velocity. We currently have a Azure hosted PostgreSQL, which holds our resources that are being created/updated by SmileCDR. Somehow after three months it is getting larger due to saving FHIR objects. Now, we want to have brand new environment; in that case persistent data in PostgreSQL has to be ripped out and new database has to be initiated with old data set.

**Please be advised.**

1. pg_dump consumes relative much more time, almost a day. How can we speed up backup-restore process?
2. What kind of alternatives that we could use and apply whereas pg_dump to achieve the goal?

**Important notes;**

- Flyway utilized by SmileCDR to make versioning in PostgreSQL.
- Everything has to be copied from old one to new one.
- PostgreSQL version is 11, 2vCores, 100GB storage.
- FHIR objects are being kept in PostgreSQL.
- Some kind of suggestions like multiple jobs, without compress, directory format have been practiced but it didn't affect significantly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you put yourself in the cage of database hosting, you have no alternative to `pg_dump`. They make it deliberately hard for you to get your data out.

The best you can do is a directory format dump with many processes; that will read data in parallel wherever possible:

```sh
pg_dump -F d -j 6 -f backupdir -h ... -p ... -U ... dbname
```

In this example, I specified 6 processes to run in parallel. This will speed up processing unless you have only one large table and all the others are quite small.

Comment: Hi Laurenz, thanks for your answer. We didn't get significant improvement in terms of creating backup with that approach. We are looking for Azure provided utilities in backupping. Thanks

Comment: Sure. Note, however, that asking for recommendations for utilities is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you may use *smileutil* with the *synchronize-fhir-servers* command, bulk export API on the system level, subscription mechanism. Just a warning that these options may be too slow to migrate the 100Gb database.
As you mentioned, if you can replicate the Azure VM that may be the fastest.

Comment: Thank you @shamil for your suggestion it is good to have it here.